# Login from local db/sqlite3 in django rest services

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

i just want to login from  `local db/sqlite3` in django Rest Services.here is my `serializer.py`

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Login.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and my `model.py` is

```
class Login(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField()
    password = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('username','password')
```

and `view.py` is

```
class LoginDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Login.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
```

and the url is `url(r'^log/', views.LoginDetail.as_view()),`

**am not sure what i did is correct or not, please excuse if its totally incorrect**
can anyone please help me create login  from local db/ sqlite3.?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: i want to login from local database...how can i achive it using these code ..? its my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup you are storing your passwords plain in your database. That's not recommended at all. A database breach will show all the passwords, as they are not hashed.

Django has their own authentication modules, which work great with Django Rest Framework. You might want to start here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/

Comment: Agreed, what is build in works day better and is definitely more secure